# Why WCF windows authentication?

Tags: wcf, security, wcf-security

Why use Windows authentication for WCF service hosted on IIS, if I can limit accessing the IP range to be "localhost", Is there a security hole here.

if not, then why Windows authentication is supported by WCF, sense I can restrict IPs for all Intranet scenarios.

thanks

Comment: Do you need authentication? impersonation? is your security based on windows roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IP range is stable (meaning very unfrequent changes on actual numbers) and you're comfortable with machines arbitrarly connected to your network having automatic access to your resources, then you may get away with your strategy. Most security officials though, will ask you to protect resources with user credentials, roles, and permissions.